# object reference is null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

There is one `MainWindow` and one `user-control` in my WPF application. I want to call function of my `MainWindow` in `user-control`, without `creating new instance of MainWindow`. For this i made main-window parent of user-control. I wrote this code below for calling function of Parent.

**Child User-Control**

```
public partial class AppLogo : UserControl
    {
    public MainWindow myparent { get; set; }
       private void activate_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           myparent.function();

         }
          . . .
     }
```

**Parent Window:**

```
      public MainWindow()
          {
            InitializeComponent();
             AppLogo childWindow = new AppLogo(); 
       . . .
```

**Questions:**

1. Is It Possible to create `Window` a parent of `user-control`?
2. If answer of above question is `Yes` then why it is generating error that `Object Reference is Null`.
3. If answer is `No it is not possible` then how can i achieve this goal. **As it is necessary to create user-control in my application as it is requirement.**

Comment: `childWindow` would be out of scope after constructor's execution..Also use [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for `MainWindow`

Comment: @Anirudh then where to define this?

Comment: @TameenMalik one quick way without is to put a static property of MainWindow of itself. public static MainWindow MainWindow { get; private set; }  and set it in the constructor MainWindow = this;

Comment: @kenny can you please provide detailed answer. will be thankful to you :)

Comment: @TameenMalik I thought I did. Just add a public static property on MainWindow that is a reference to itself and set in the constructor. You can access it anywhere since it's a public static/class variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have reference in `UserControl` to `MainWindow` use following code:

```
MainWindow mw = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx

```
private void activate_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mw = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
    if(mw != null)
    {
        mw.function();
    }
}
```

*Second solution:*

In your code you should set `myparent` property in `MainWindow` constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AppLogo childWindow = new AppLogo(); 
    childWindow.myparent = this;
    ...
}
```

In `activate_Click_1` event handler the good habit is check if `myparent` is not null:

```
private void activate_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(myparent != null)
        myparent.function();
    else
        ...
}
```

Comment: again it is saying that object reference is null

Comment: @TameenMalik could you debug your code and check if `Application.Current.MainWindow` is null ?

Comment: So this code should work. @TameenMalik what is in `Application.Current.MainWindow` property?, what is type of this object? To get type you can use this code: `Debug.WriteLine(Application.Current.MainWindow.GetType().FullName);`

Comment: There is some problem with my PC... can i catch you later

Comment: Hi Thank's, i had some serious issue. Thank's for patience. ok it's output is `WpfApplication7.Administration`  --- `Administartion` is window in which i am using this `UserControl`

Comment: @TameenMalik check my answer again.

Comment: Thank's for response! i don't know what's wrong with my application .. i used these same lines but it didn't  work :'( it works only when i use window without `user-control`...

Comment: @TameenMalik if you make example project I will look where is bug in your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37549/discussion-between-kmatyaszek-and-tameen-malik)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the null reference is for the `myparent` property on `AppLogo`?

After this line `AppLogo childWindow = new AppLogo();` add one saying `childWindow.myparent = this;`

Comment: i added this, but problem is same

Answer (score 0):

You may introduce a child parent dependecy as suggested, however since you didn't instantiate MainWindow you should expect a null reference exception when calling myparent.function();

First, you need to instantiate MainWindow, and then set the child parent relationship by calling AppLogo .set_myparent, only then your call won't fail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference to the instance of MainWindow as an argument to AppLogo's constructor, then set it to AppLogo's variable for MainWindow.

```
public AppLogo(MainWindow mainWindow)
{
    this.myparent = mainWindow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you locate your `UserControl` directly inside your `Window`, then its `Parent` property will reference your window.
2. The exception is called when you try to access the field which contains `null` value. It contains `null` because noone placed there anything else. You might want to set it:

   ```
   AppLogo childWindow = new AppLogo(); 
   childWindow.myparent = <something>;
   ```
3. You just need to recursively search your UserControl's parents until you get an instance of a `Window`, which will be your goal.

---

```
public static Window GetWindow(FrameworkElement element)
{
    return (element.Parent as Window) ?? GetWindow(element.Parent);
}
```

Comment: how to recursively search  UserControl's parents

Comment: Error Generated: Error2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' to 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement'